# Add new property to Action in TActionList

Tags: delphi, taction, tactionlist

How can I add new published (to be shown in Object Inspector) property to the Action of TActionList in Delphi

the property data type is Boolean.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create your new action class by deriving from `TAction`. For example:

```
TMyAction = class(TAction)
...
published
  property MyBoolProp: Boolean ....
end;
```

And then you can register it from your design time package's `Register` procedure by calling [`RegisterActions`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ActnList.RegisterActions).

```
procedure Register;
begin
  .... // register any other components
  RegisterActions('MyCategory', [TMyAction], nil);
end;
```

Then from the action list editor, select `New Standard Action` and your action will appear in the tree view of available actions.

[image]

[image]

---

In the comments you seem to imply that you want to modify `TAction` to have a new property. That would require modification to the VCL itself and that's beyond your control. No doubt the VCL could be hacked to achieve what you ask for but that's not a good idea.

Comment: I want it to appear when I add new action in TActionList
if you want to understand me do the following :

Open New project
add TActionList on the form
double click on the TActionList
Add new Action Item

I want the added action item to have new property..thats it

Comment: Ooh, I'm feeling the love today on SO!!  ;-)

Comment: Ah, the community sticky note has disappeared from the right side bar. It said: "Week two of the summer of love" or similar...

Comment: @Marjan, now I [`got that`](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/week-2-of-the-summer-of-love-researching-comments/) :-)